# sql query for get customer name

Tags: mysql

hi am new in mysql.i want to fetch the customer name from customer table .if the customer id of customer table and the another customer id of work order table are should be same.how to write this query

Answer (score 1):

try

```
SELECT c.name
FROM table_customer c
INNER JOIN table_work_order w
ON w.customer_id=c.customer_id
```

**note:** make the **index** on `customer_id` of both tables

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT C.name FROM customer as C , work_orders as WO
where C.customer_id = WO.customer_id
AND WO.work_order_id = 25
```

try this If you want to get work-order's customer name. try this.